# How do I extract each words from a text file in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, indexing, text-files

I'm pretty much new to Scala. I have a text file that has only one line with file words separated by a semi-colon(;).
I want to extract each word, remove the white spaces, convert all to lowercase and call them based on the index of each word. Below is how I approached it:

```
newListUpper2.txt contains (Bed;  chairs;spoon; CARPET;curtains )
val file = sc.textFile("myfile.txt")
val lower = file.map(x=>x.toLowerCase)
val result = lower.flatMap(x=>x.trim.split(";"))
result.collect.foreach(println)
```

Below is the copy of the REPL when I executed the code

```
    scala> val file = sc.textFile("newListUpper2.txt")
    file: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = newListUpper2.txt MapPartitionsRDD[5] at textFile at 
    <console>:24
    scala> val lower = file.map(x=>x.toLowerCase)
    lower: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[6] at map at <console>:26
    scala> val result = lower.flatMap(x=>x.trim.split(";"))
    result: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[7] at flatMap at <console>:28
    scala> result.collect.foreach(println)
bed                                                                          
 chairs
spoon
 carpet
curtains
scala> result(0)
<console>:31: error: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] does not take parameters
       result(0)
```

The results are not trimmed and then passing the index as parameter to get the word at that index gives error. My expected outcome should be as stated below if I pass the index of each word as parameter

```
result(0)= bed
result(1) = chairs
result(2) = spoon
result(3) = carpet
result(4) = curtains
```

What am I doing wrong?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
newListUpper2.txt contains (Bed;  chairs;spoon; CARPET;curtains )
val file = sc.textFile("myfile.txt")
val lower = file.map(x=>x.toLowerCase)
val result = lower.flatMap(x=>x.trim.split(";")) // x = `bed;  chairs;spoon; carpet;curtains` , x.trim does not work. trim func effective for head and tail only
result.collect.foreach(println)
```

Try it:

```
val result = lower.flatMap(x=>x.split(";").map(x=>x.trim))
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Issue 1

```
scala> result(0)
<console>:31: error: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] does not take parameters
```

result is a RDD and it cant take parameters in this format. Instead you can use `result.show(10,false)`

2) Issue 2 - To achieve like this - `result(0)= bed ,result(1) = chairs.....`

```
scala> var result = scala.io.Source.fromFile("/path/to/File").getLines().flatMap(x=>x.split(";").map(x=>x.trim)).toList
result: List[String] = List(Bed, chairs, spoon, CARPET, curtains)

scala> result(0)
res21: String = Bed

scala> result(1)
res22: String = chairs
```